# Improve UI performance on heavy work loop

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, performance, loops

I have a "time line" in my application, consisting of many labels (dynamic) that get placed according to their relative position in the time scale.

I have another section below this, which is the "legends" section for the time line. When hovering over a particular legend, I step through the time line, and set all the non relevant labels to `visible = false`, and the relevant labels to `visible`. This allows the user to hover over a certain legend label, and see it represented alone on the time line.

*Extra Info*
When a user exits the legend(label) hover, I restore all the lines (labels) on the timeline to visible.
*/Extra info*

This all works really well, but some of my time scales, have 800+ labels on them (thin lines).

The interface updates in about 3-5 seconds in this case, which is acceptable, but the CPU REALLY battles to keep up.

When testing, my music player stutters big time whenever I run this code to interact with the time line. As soon as the loop is finished, the cpu catches up again.

As I really don't want to use a `doEvents()` (not that it really helps.. I tried), what other suggestions can you offer to give the cpu some breathing time.

What I have done so far:

1. Set the containing panel to invisible before the loop begins, and visible when it completes.
2. Suspend and Resume layout does not seem to make any difference to performance, I had better results with the visibility trick in point 1.
3. I am already re-using labels, and don't add/remove them when I need to show them.
4. Should I implement threading.thread.sleep, just for a few milliseconds, after each loop iteration? (Is this acceptable practice)
5. My form is set to double buffered.
6. The labels may be a bit "heavy", as they have a plethora of extra properties and features/events that I don't use. Is there a better alternative?

My code:

```
 Private Sub label_hovered(appname As String) Handles myAwesomeViewLegend.labelHover

        Try

            blockPanel.Visible = False

            For Each l As Label In blockPanel.Controls
                If l.Text = appname Then
                    l.Visible = True

                Else
                    l.Visible = False
                End If

            Next

            blockPanel.Visible = True

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim method_name As String = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
            Dim method_class As String = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType.FullName
            MsgBox(ex.tostring & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & method_name & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & method_class)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `l.Visible = False` only when `l.Visible = True`? I.e. `If l.Visible Then l.Visible = False`

Comment: I haven't tried it, but the majority of the labels (lines) are being set to visible = false, on each run. The labels being shown, are a tiny percentage of the whole thing. I also failed to mention that I restore all the labels to visible, when hovering out of the legend (label).

Comment: I will implement your suggestion none the less, as I like saving any cpu cycle that I can. Thanks.

Comment: Using labels in this way is a bad idea. You would be much better to plot the text using GDI+ as it will be much less resource intensive

Comment: Thanks @MattWilko , I am considering this. I have a tooltip on each label, to show some info when you hover over the lines. This means I will have to somehow rig up events to do this when entering the positions of my lines on the screen. Will this not cause "more" overhead than what I am currently doing?

Comment: No, you can respond to the mousehover event, loop through your array of label locations in memory and find the first one that overlaps. You can even do this asynchronously...

Comment: Sounds like a plan, I will definitely consider it, thanks.

Comment: @MattWilko, thinking about it again, this would mean redrawing all lines on every legend hover? Will that not be more costly in the end?

Comment: No you just draw on the paint event

Comment: The drawing of the relevant lines, will be a small percentage of the whole, so that's fine. But I show "all" the lines once you hover out of a legend label. This means I would have to redraw, 800+ lines (blocks), each time I exit a legend label. I am not very experienced in GDI drawing, hence my question about performance.

Comment: Are you able to create and cache an image and when hovering the legend showing the matching image.

Comment: That's a good idea but I think it will introduce other problems (in my specific scenario). I will take it into account none the less. Thanks for the good suggestion.

Comment: @MattWilko , Please add your suggestions about drawing everything as an answer. I have taken the time to physically draw everything on my charting control, instead of using labels. I have a performance increase of unmeasurable proportions. It was a lot less overhead this way, like you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would construct only the visible labels. I think it is a bad practice creating 800 labels and toggle the `Visibility` property.

Create a sorted list with times and check if a time should be visible by calculating the start and endtime (window). Create labels for the (should be visible) times.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when initially viewing the timeline, I show "everything". All lines representing everything on the timeline. You can then "filter" the time line, by hovering over the legend labels.

Comment: The slow scenario is a worst case scenario. Where you would select multiple days, with a lot of action for each day. For the normal daily operation, it is quite responsive. I am looking to tidy it up as much as possible on the higher levels.